# Need the sql query based on some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
select CardCode, ItemCode, T0.DocDate, ''[CustomerType]  from OINV T0 inner Join INV1 T1 on T1.DocEntry = T0.DocEntry and year(T0.DocDate) >= year(getdate()) -4
```

I have added one more column called  'CustomerType' will look like '**New**', '**Existing**', '**One more Product**'

Conditions to check based on the **docdate** and **itemcode** column:

1. e.g. Now is year 2020, if 2019 there is no sales, then customertype is  = ‘**New**’ else '**Existing**' . Need to check based on '**CardCode**' column
2. eg: Those customer type 'existing' i need to check if they purchase the itemcode before or not if they purchased then customertype remains as 'existing' if not should reflect as '**One more Product**'. Need to check based on '**ItemCode**' column

sample result set:

```
CardCode    ItemCode    DocDate     CustomerType
C-SGD-2748  V0796-0038  2017-01-24 
C-SGD-1489  V0796-0066  2020-06-10 
C-SGD-2748  V0796-0106  2019-01-15  
C-SGD-1489  V0796-0130  2019-05-17 
C-SGD-2652  V0805-0001  2016-12-08
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results you want in the question.  (3) You can also clean up the explanation a bit.  It is hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` and window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(docdate) over (partition by cardcode) >= '2020-01-01'
             then 'New'
             when row_number() over (partition by cardcode, itemcode order by docdate) > 1
             then 'existing'
             else 'one more product'
        end) as customertype
```

I find these types to be rather confusing.  However, this seems to be exactly what you are describing.

Comment: (partition by cardcode) >= '2020-01-01' . is it hard coded . can be based on the year. Basically new means has no any transaction (zero) records  on previous year.

Comment: Thank you for the query. Basically the the CustomerType 'New' means has no any transcation (zero) records on previous year

Comment: @VignaHariKarthik . . .You can use `year(getdate())`, but you question specifically mentions the date which is why I used it.

Comment: My "New" customer type should work if there no sales on last year 2019 but got sales in 2020 then it is new based on the docdate. How do modify my query ?