# Need the SQL query based on the Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

This is my SQL query

```
select CardCode, ItemCode, DocDate, DocYear from OINV
```

I need to add on more column called **customertype**

1. New =>  if there is no purchase transaction based on the last year. 2020 last year is 2019, 2019 last year is 2018,2018 last year is 2017, 2017 last year is 2016 and so on. Then the customertype is "**new**".
2. OneMoreProduct => item code is base on per customer item code history 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017 and so on, if 1st time buying this item code. Then the customertype is "**onemoreproduct**"
3. Existing => If the above two condition is not tally then it is "**existing**"

I need to write an case based on these three type.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) I.e. [mcve].

Comment: Basically the same question as your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897716/need-the-sql-query-based-on-some-condition)

Comment: Previous question i didnt put proper request. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to CASE statement for a column.

Your rules are not apparent, since you did not post sample DDL and sample data.
If you want a good answer, then post the DDL, insert sample data...and then ask the question.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

But here is a generic answer.

```
select CardCode, ItemCode, DocDate, DocYear ,
    [customertype] =
    CASE    
        WHEN 1=1 Then 'new'
        WHEN 2=2 Then 'onemoreproduct'
        ELSE 'existing'
    END
FROM OINV
```

You will "code up" the WHEN statements to your needs.

Comment: Hi i know the case condition, i dont have  sample to check

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, the available window functions are limited.  One method uses a `case` expression:

```
select o.*,
       (case when not exists (select 1
                              from oinv o2
                              where o2.cardcode = o.cardcode and
                                    o2.docyear = o.docyear - 1
                             )
             then 'New'
             when row_number() over (partition by cardcode, itemcode order by date) = 1
             then 'OneMoreProduct'
             else 'Existing'
        end) as customertype
from oinv o;
```

Comment: Sorry my sql is 2016

Comment: when row_number() over (partition by CardCode, ItemCode order by date) = 1 or  when row_number() over (partition by CardCode, ItemCode order by docdate)

Comment: @VignaHariKarthik . . . This works in SQL Server 2016 as well.

Comment: I need to add an where condition in this statement how can i achieve it ?when row_number() over (partition by cardcode, itemcode where oniv.itemgroupcode =10  order by date) = 1.

Comment: @VignaHariKarthik . . . Add a `where` to the outer query.  I doubt you need it on the subquery, but you might need it there as well.